# How to match a quoted string with escaped quotes in it?

Tags: php, regex

```
/^"((?:[^"]|\\.)*)"/
```

Against this string:

```
"quote\_with\\escaped\"characters" more
```

It only matches until the `\"`, although I've clearly defined `\` as an escape character (and it matches `\_` and `\\` fine...).

Comment: Is there a worse question than "what is wrong with the regex?" - No offense CX.

Comment: I know, right :D
What would you have titled it?

Comment: @Rob: should this question be phrased differently? Or are questions about regular expressions that do not behave as expected not appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Title is fine.  Reading and debugging RegEx is a pain.  Sorry to confuse.

Comment: @Core Xii: what is the platform/regular expression dialect? Perl, Java, Python, .NET ? (Looks like Perl from your example.)

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Perl dialect in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works correctly if you flip the order of your two alternatives:

```
/^"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"/
```

The problem is that otherwise the important `\` character gets eaten up **before** it tries matching `\"`.  It worked before for `\\` and `\_` only because both characters in either pair get matched by your `[^"]`.

Comment: Simple mistake with the order of things, brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Python with raw-string literals to ensure no further interpretation of escape sequences is taking place, the following variant does work:

```
import re

x = re.compile(r'^"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"')

s = r'"quote\_with\\escaped\"characters" more"'

mo = x.match(s)
print mo.group()
```

emits `"quote\_with\\escaped\"characters"`; I believe that in your version (which also interrupts the match precociously if substituted in here) the "not a doublequote" subexpression (`[^"]`) is swallowing the backslashes that you intend to be taken as escaping the immediately-following characters. All I'm doing here is ensuring that such backslashes are NOT swallowed in this way, and, as I said, it seems to work with this change.

Answer (score 0):

Not intend to confuse, just another information I've played around with. Below regexp(PCRE) try to not match wrong syntax (eg. end with \") and can use with both ' or "

```
/('|").*\\\1.*?[^\\]\1/
```

to use with php

```
<?php if (preg_match('/(\'|").*\\\\\1.*?[^\\\\]\1/', $subject)) return true; ?>
```

For:

```
"quote\_with\\escaped\"characters"  "aaa"
'just \'another\' quote "example\"'
"Wrong syntax \"
"No escapes, no match here"
```

This only match:

```
"quote\_with\\escaped\"characters" and
'just \'another\' quote "example\"'
```